# How to redirect from IIS to an internal server and use Let's Encrypt to validate the original URL domain?

Tags: iis, lets-encrypt

My problem: Can't redirect from IIS to an internal server and use Let's Encrypt to validate the original URL domain.

I use IIS as a kind of reverse proxy where one site redirects to another internal server. I use the standard HTML IIS Redirect applet, which works well. The problem is when I want to install Let's Encrypt cert on this internal server, and the cert should verify the original URL and domain.

The redirect from IIS is an IP adress to the internal server. As expected I run into problems on the internal server, which "sees" only the incoming IP adress, not the original URL (before redirection) with the original domain name.

I would be very grateful if someone could point me to some docs or precedures on where I should install the cert, and how it can verify the original domain, not the internal IP. I assume I have to do something clever on the IIS.

And - yes I have been using NGINX for several years. But when I wanted to use Microsoft Account verification on the internal servers, I never got it to work behind NGINX, even if I have scrutinized "every possible" article on the subject. So I ditched NGINX and use IIS directly, which solves 80% of my tasks.

Comment: Are you actually redirecting to the internal server or is IIS configured as an actual reverse proxy?

Comment: Do you need HTTPS between your frontend IIS server and your backend internal server?   If this is on a trusted local network, it may be fine just to use HTTP for that portion.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The IIS site is (problably) just setup as a redirect to the internal server. I just used the builtin "redirect applet" inside IIS Manager. 
My previous NGINX setup handled HTTPS/Let´s  Encrypt, and internal traffic was HTTP. I am no IIS guru - very far from it - but a similar setup ONLY for this particular site would probably be what I want, as long as the other sites on the same IIS are NOT affected.

Comment: If it is an internal sever, how do external clients access it by its internal IP address?

Comment: I should probably rephrase the question, after having learned a bit more, and reading your previous answers, thank you! 
I removed the redirection, and the followed this article, except about creating the site, which was already there. https://tevpro.com/blog/using-iis-as-a-reverse-proxy-server/
But it seems as the local server (nextcloud) is unhappy and I can't install a new cert. When connection that internal server directly to the net, I can install a new cert, and it works well. But when the traffic goes through the IIS, with the rewrite as in the article, I only get page not found.